# trying to pass fileinputstream obj from function into another function

Tags: java, function, selenium-webdriver, fileinputstream

I would like to use a function to read from a properties file and than use the object of that file at various places.here is what I have tried so far with no luck.

```
public class all_the_functions 

 {
    public FileInputStream loadPropertiesFile(FileInputStream obj2) throws IOException
     {
       //reading from the properties file
       Properties obj = new Properties();
       FileInputStream fileobj = new FileInputStream("//Users//macuser//Desktop//selenium//project_Mat//input_properties.properties");
       obj.load(fileobj);
       return fileobj;  
     }
 }
```

And than in my main function I am using the following code

```
public class searchdynamic();
{
    FileInputStream Obj;
    all_the_functions func = new all_the_functions();
    func.loadPropertiesFile(Obj);     
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to(Obj.getproperty("valid URL");
}
```

The end goal is to read from. The input file by using the function and stroung the properties file so that I can always call the same function when I need to read from the file. Can someone please point me to what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34187678/edit) to include what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can u try this

```
public class searchdynamic();
{
    FileInputStream Obj;
    all_the_functions func = new all_the_functions();
    Obj=func.loadPropertiesFile(Obj);     
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to(Obj.getproperty("valid URL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the string that your property is returning? "http://www..."

In theory, this should work (although I'm used to webdriver being navigate().GoToUrl(string url).  Give that a shot...

Also, friendly warning about this being not oop or compiling.  Might be a good idea to tie your properties to values somehow.  I understand this is a keyword driven framework, but it is better practice to have a user input "Google" and have your code digest that into something like

`driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com"); // (c#)`

This way, you can count on correct input and handle incorrect input appropriately.

Regardless, try .Navigate().GoToUrl()